# Trying to get the query of customers

Tags: sql-server-2008

Customers respective orders:

```
    Companyname , Contactname, OrderID, OrderDate
```

Sort by orderid from most recent to the oldest.

I tried this but no luck - can anyone help me out?

```
SELECT companyname, contactname, orderid, orderdate, COUNT(DISTINCT contactname) 
FROM Sales.Customers
INNER JOIN Sales.Orders ON Sales.Customers.contactname = Sales.Orders.orderid
```

Comment: What is the issue with your query ? What is not working ?

Comment: Have you tried `ORDER BY orderid asc`?